# Rank of a free resolution of an ideal generated by three elements at a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need to study the free resolution of an ideal and I am doing the following argument:

Let $X$ be a smooth (complex) surface $p\in X$,  and $I=(a,b,c)< \mathcal{O}_X$ a sheaf of ideals. Let $\phi: \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus 3} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ be the $\mathcal{O}_X$-morphism given by $\phi(f,g,h)=af+bg+ch$. Then $K = \mathrm{ker}(\phi)$ is a coherent reflexive sheave, and then locally free.

To discover the rank of $K$, I considered the open set $U=X-Z(c)$, where $af+bg+ch=0$ iff $h = -\frac{1}{c}\cdot(af+bg)$, and then  $K|_{U} = \mathcal{O}_U \cdot (1,0, -\frac{a}{c}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_U \cdot (0,1, -\frac{b}{c}) $. This imply that the rank of $K$ is $2$.

Then arises some questions:

- First I don't know if it's right, because it seems to me a very generic affirmation.
- By this argument, $K_p\simeq \mathcal{O}_{X,p}^{\otimes 2}$, but is it possible to know the generators? I can suppose $gcd(a,c) = gcd(b,c)= gcd(a,b)=1$ and that $Z(I)=p$ if it helps.
- How to make this kind of argument in commutative algebra dictionary? Is there some "syzygy theorem" that gives the rank of the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $Z\subset X$ the subscheme given by simultaneous vanishing of $a,b$ and $c$. We have an exact sequence
$$0\to I\to\mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_Z\to 0.$$

At any $x\notin Z$ the stalk $I_x$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ (since localization is an exact functor), therefore $I_x\otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}}\mathbb C(x)\cong\mathbb C$ (here $\mathbb C(x)$ is the residue field of the point $x\in X$. Hence the exact sequence
$$0\to K\to\mathcal O_X^{\oplus 3}\to I\to 0$$
of locally free sheaves induces an exact sequence
$$0\to K_x\otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}}\mathbb C(x)\to\mathbb C^3\to \mathbb C\to 0$$
of complex vector spaces (since locally free sheaves are flat). Of course, this implies $\dim K_x\otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}}\mathbb C(x)=2$, so the sheaf $K$ has rank 2. As for generators at a point $p\in Z$, I don't know.